# Which are the word orders that can be found in English?

Tags: word-order, dialects

Besides [SVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object), which are the [word orders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order) that can be found in English? Are there any that are peculiar to dialects such as Singlish or Indian English? Please provide an example sentence for each order along with pertinent information such as tense, mood, voice, etc.

Comment: [OSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93subject%E2%80%93verb#English_and_German) can also be found in English sometimes.

Comment: @A. This I already knew. :)

Comment: SVO is the ground state. Deviations from this (and other norms) by syntactic rules are used to form variant clause and phrase types,  to indicate focussed elements, to express emotions, and to improve parseability. Depending on the rules, of course.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you aware of anything that summarises or tabulates all of these deviations? I'm particularly interested to know if any orders are local only to certain dialects.

Comment: That's sociolinguistics, not syntax. If you want a summary of syntactic rules, try [this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf).

Comment: There are 6 arrangements for SVO, maybe we can give 6 examples...

Comment: You might want to check out transformational grammar for English.

Comment: I think this is Not A Real Question, in that it's "overly broad", and can't reasonably be addressed in a single answer here on ELU.

Comment: At its simplest, this is a HWQ; at its best, it is a linguistics Q. I suggest migrating to either ELL or linguisticsSE -- I'm leaving it open on ELU for now.

Comment: coleopterist If didn't ask on linguisticsSE, there must a good reason?

Comment: @Kris This is a question specifically pertaining to English. It's perfect for this site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is, at least apparently, a homework question, quite likely, one.

Comment: See Prof Lawler's comment above on sociolinguistic nature of the question.

Answer (score 1):

All of them, though often at the stretch of hyperbaton, so most of them would be rare. Still, a short story in 6 word-orders:

> SVO "I love you"
>
> VOS "Take me, dear"
>
> VSO Here comes the bride! [No object, but if there was an object it would follow here]
>
> SOV "With this ring, I thee wed".
>
> OVS Passion does not a lifetime make
>
> OSV "I won't talk to him, but my lawyer, I will call".

Comment: I'd take issue with your VOS and VSO.  The VOS is really two sentences apposed, or in parataxis.  You might go instead for, "Like books, I do".  The VSO sentence doesn't contain an O, just the intransitive verb "come" with the S "the bride".  Since only auxiliary (and like) verbs front, it's hard to give an example, but, in British English, you could go for "Have you any books?".

Comment: Neither your nor @DanielHarbour 's VOS sentences make any sense at all to me coming from an English speaker unless I picture Yoda saying them.

Comment: If you allow imperatives, V O S is fairly easy. *"Behold my works, ye Mighty, and despair!"*

Comment: @T.E.D. updated to a more plausible example.

Comment: @PeterShor I was always taught imperatives had an implicit "You" for a subject at the start of the sentence. So its still vanilla SVO, with some extra phrases tacked on. Perhaps like "(S)VO, S, V"

Comment: @T.E.D. imperatives have an implicit second-person subject, except when they have an explicit second-person subject. Peter's example, and that in my updated answer, each have explicit subjects.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be more receptive to the argument that the whole "implicit subject" thing was BS made up to shoehorn the language into rules that aren't, and English imperatives are really "VO". If we allow for "implicit subjects", then IMHO they are *always* there on imperatives, and any clarifying phrases you tack on later are just that.

Comment: @T.E.D. the idea of implicit subject deals simply enough with the fact that it does act as if it has a second-person subject when there's no subject in the statement, with the number of that subject deducible from context (or sometimes ambiguous) while it can also have explicit subject (second person single, second person plural, second person ambiguous or first person plural) too.

Answer (score -3):

Well as a Singaporean, I can help answer your question. Singlish, is not a dialect. Instead, it is a term used mainly by Singaporeans. Although Singlish is not a proper language, it still has a relatively extensive range of vocabulary. For example, a person speaking proper English will say: "Go and turn off the heater!" On the other hand, a person speaking in Singlish will say:"Go and switch off the heater lah!" In Singlish, when someone wishes to emphasize himself, he will end off with a forceful "lah" The word is a common slang added by Singaporeans. When someone adds a "lah" at the back of his/her sentence, the person ussually means that he is stating the obvious. Singlish is commonly regarded with low prestige in Singapore. The Singaporean government and many upper class Singaporeans alike heavily discourage the use of Singlish in favour of Standard English. The vocabulary of Singlish consists of words originating from English, Malay, Hokkien, Teochew, Cantonese, Tamil and to a lesser extent various other European, Indic and Sinitic languages. Also, elements of American and Australian slang have come through from imported television series and films. Thus, there are nearly a countless number of Singlish words. In fact there are so many, till listing them down will take a ages. Instead, you may look up "Singlish" on wikipedia. Also, they sell a guide in Singapore called:"Singlish for Idiots" which, as the title implies, contains a "textbook" to Singlish. Sadly, I am not yet sure about Indian English being a dialect and i will update this post as soon as possible. With more info on Indian English. Oh, and one more thing Singlish is not a dialect as it can be written in words.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by things being or not being dialects. What do you consider “dialect” to mean?

Comment: @tchrist You don't? Or was that a rhetorical question (more likely)?