# Location - sentence constructions

Tags: grammar

Having studied English from an early age, I've been always taught that English has a fixed sentence structure and words within it appear in a fixed order.

For example, one is supposed to say: *A pen is on the table.* Or: *There is a pen on the table.* According to this principle (the subject coming before the predicate), one shouldn't say: *On the table is a pen.*

However, reading some English books and articles, I've noticed a violation of this rule. I've seen it in sentences like these:

- In the east is the Atlantic coast.
- In the far north is the famous Arctic region.
- In the mountain region are big deposits of coal.

What is the justification of these structures? Are they correct?

Comment: Perfectly fine. The word order in English much more flexible than you were taught (*and then* there's things like [hyperbaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton) on top of that, ubiquitous especially in higher registers). If you learn a bogus rule, you are bound to find out that the rule is bogus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which are the word orders that can be found in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108235/which-are-the-word-orders-that-can-be-found-in-english)

Answer (score 1):

*On the table is a pen

But in the cup, there are ten

Show good manners – put it back

Lest cleanliness is what we lack*

That's a silly poem that could be found on a sign in a copy shop, exhorting customers to put pens back in a cup, rather than leave them on the tabletop. (Perhaps an exasperated owner was tired of putting them back in the cup all day long, or maybe a customer's project was ruined after erroneously spreading it over what she thought was a smooth service.)

Anyhow, my point is this: "correct" is a loaded word. A sentence from a newspaper article or textbook may seem like it needs to be rewritten, but there are other contexts – such as poetry – where the wording may sound fine or even natural.

English may have guidelines for how to assemble sentences, but it's a very flexible language with plenty of wiggle room for variants.

Comment: Yes, generally *a pen is on the table* is just lesson n.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's well known technique: the use of the **fronted adverbial**. Entirely correct.

You'll find many great references searching at Google Books (not vanilla Google) for:

["fronted adverbial"](https://www.google.com/search?q=fronting%20adverbial%20&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22fronted%20adverbial%22)