# Why does the sentence "Glimpses do ye seem to see of that (...) ?" starts with 'glimpses' instead of with regular 'do'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, questions, do

I cannot make much sense of ***glimpses*** in the following passage from [Moby-Dick](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701):

> Know ye now, Bulkington? ***Glimpses*** do ye seem to see of that mortally intolerable truth; that all deep, earnest thinking is but the intrepid effort of the soul to keep the open independence of her sea; while the wildest winds of heaven and earth conspire to cast her on the treacherous, slavish shore?

Why did Melville begin this somewhat lengthy question with ***glimpses*** instead of with ***do***?

The following would make more sense to me:

> Do ye seem to see that mortally intolerable truth;(...)?

[The research I've done so far](https://rewordify.com/index.php?u=k4wrx3jhcw6pzm) does not clear up anything to me.

Comment: He moves *glipses* to the front of the sentence in order to emphasize the word, and possibly to make his prose sound more poetical.

Comment: [**Poetic inversion**.](https://quizlet.com/83925956/poetic-devices-flash-cards/) *When the words of a sentence or phrase are out of normal order.* From Thus Spoke Zarathustra - [*Two kings do I see — and only one ass!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Two+kings+do+I+see%22)

Comment: Much have I travell'd in the realms of gold,
And many goodly states and kingdoms seen...    Thus starts off Keats his "Looking into Chapman's Homer". It is common to see writers fiddle around with words to achieve desired effects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which are the word orders that can be found in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108235/which-are-the-word-orders-that-can-be-found-in-english) This is the rare OVS structure, with a complicating interrogative verb phrase. _Answers were there none._ is a simpler example. _Answers did there seem to be any?_ is pushing it.

Comment: @Edwin It does very well. As well as the examples adduced by Peter, FumbleFingers, and Stockfish - thanks to y'all.

Comment: Please note that some word orders are very rare and stylised.