# 'Further than that I Cannot Go...' What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

Reading the text, I found the next fragment. The author apologizes to a friend for an oversight and writes the following:

> If, in some weeks time, you see a dog-like shape [...], it will be me. look carefully as its smarmy rump that asks to be kicked, its trembling, penholding paw that scribbles, "kick me", in the dust [...] I was worried [...] and should, anyway, in a few days have sent off an explanation to you. **Further than that I Cannot Go**, but you may still kick me when we meet again.
>
> (From a [letter to Vernon Watkins](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LXjhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT447&lpg=PT447&dq=%22I+had+actually+very+little+myself+to+do+with+the+editing%22&source=bl&ots=G4Ms2yQeCO&sig=ACfU3U3VUn-tCRL-0KC5N8U7HhvHhaF39w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwioteDqw433AhUUyzgGHbZXDh8Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22I%20had%20actually%20very%20little%20myself%20to%20do%20with%20the%20editing%22&f=false) dated 15th July, 1937)

So, what does the phrase "Further than that I Cannot Go" mean?
"I could hardly do more than send a letter of explanation?" or "A kick is all I'm willing to take, but I won't settle for more torture."

And why are three words in capital letters? Is this just the author's whim?

Comment: ***The best that I can offer to do to help you** is that I invite you to imagine that in some weeks time you might see a dog that you can pretend is **me**, and I invite you to imagine kicking that dog* (you can't kick ***me***, but I'm prepared to let you imagine kicking a dog that you can *think* is me).

Comment: Thank you! That's a good explanation.

Comment: Personal letters, not meant for public publishing, can often indulge in usages, styles, and constructions that are understood by and acceptable to both the writer and recipient. I wonder whether the capitalization indicates an allusion or quote—the phrase "further than that I cannot go" seems to be found in a Kafka short story published in 1931, though he may also be inserting "than that" into "further I cannot go."

Comment: @AndyBonner: Surely any "Kafka short story published in 1931" would have been written in Gerrman? But this stylised "inversion" from standard *I cannot say/do/go further/more* has always been common in English - there's no need to look for foreign sources.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed, though the English translation with that phrase was published 1933. And if we delete "than that," it could be allusion to any of thousands of sources (George Washington said "further I cannot go"); or maybe it's not an allusion at all, but just a spate of capitalization for emphasis. All speculation on my part; a Dylan Thomas scholar might know more about shared context with the recipient.

Comment: @AndyBonner: Actually, I wasn't paying proper attention when I looked at this page before. I didn't notice either the non-standard capitalisation itself, or your reference to it. I can't think why Thomas would have gone for that quirky capitalisation. He was a bit of a drinker, so *feasibly* he just continued after having capitalised the first person singular pronoun because he was a bit tanked. Or perhaps as you suggested, it reflected some kind of in-joke or private history with the recipient. But I think I was probably on the right track simply not noticing it first time around. Meaningless

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or, "meaningful only to the author and recipient." (Or maybe a sufficiently informed outside party.) The fact remains, when we read published private correspondences, we're not the intended audience, and if we find it puzzling, it's our fault for eavesdropping.

Comment: Well, that puts *us* in our place, then! :)

Comment: He's expressing contrition, at the same time as saying he will only do so much to apologise. The phrase "Further than that I cannot go" is grammatically simple and self-evident in meaning. The reference to the dog is performative contrition. The confusion is about exactly what the situation is, how sincere his apology/contrition is, whether he could really have done more than he is doing, whether his present apology and forthcoming explanation suffice, whether he'll do what he promises, and a host of other issues. Which are for the biographer, not the grammarian.

Comment: This is a very common phenomenon in English and it has a number of different names. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/586497/15299) covers most of the bases.